# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, glassfish

Tengo problemas con levantar el .war. Funcionaba super bien en Glassfish, pero de un momento a otro sin ningún tipo de cambio, dejó de funcionar. He configurado el asenv.bat con

```
set AS_JAVA  =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
```

Pero no funciona sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: revisa que C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91  en verdad exista

Comment: @Elenasys ya lo solucione, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Elsa Que bien , que sucedía? agrega tu respuesta para que ayude a otros! y la marco como aceptada!  saludos

Comment: Hola @elsa. Por favor publica el contenido del comentario en una respuesta, pasado los dos días podrás marcarlo como respuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza como hago eso?

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una gran caja de texto que es para la sección de respuestas. Allí publica el contenido de los pasos para la solución. Luego la podrás aceptar.

Answer (score 1):

por alguna razón que desconozco, el path se había desconfigurado, perdiéndose también el JAVA_HOME, entonces lo configure nuevamente, el tema es que aun no me funcionaba, es importante que el cambio quede bien realizado, verificando por CDM, con el comando 'set' muestra las variables, y para mi sorpresa, no estaba siendo tomadas pero en las configuraciones avanzada si estaban guardadas, entonces para que el sistema lo tomara, se tuvo que reiniciar el pc, despues de eso, revise nuevamente por cmd y ya aparecieron. eso :)